# can I limit number of indexing fields in elasticsearch 5.3

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

new to Elasticsearch. I see by default, ES creates indexes for every word in every field. But in my use-case, I will be searching only two fields, so am thinking to tell ES somehow that dont create index for everything in the document, but create indexes only the fields I specify in the mapping.

SO here is my mapping

```
PUT /benefits
  { 
     "mappings": {
       "benefit": {
         "_all": {"enabled": false},
          "properties": {
            "subCategory": {"type": "text"},
            "description": {"type": "text"}
         }  

       }
   }
}
```

and my document looks like this

```
{
"bpi" : "123456",
"category" : "CAT1",
"subCategory" : "Primary Care Physician Copay",
"planName" : "MyPlan HMO Individual",
"description" : "0 per office visit for Convenient Care & Minute Clinics Complete ABC Document",
"categoryId" : 200.0,
"desktop360Id" : 1001.0,
"createTimeStamp" : "2017-02-21T22:00:12.000Z"
```

}

So I will be searching only on `"subCategory"` and `"description"` (not on `"planName"` or any other fields text) and created the index/mapping as shown in mapping above, but I am still able to search text on other fields as well. for example if I search "MyPlan" from `"planName"` field, the search works and brings up this document. Does it mean it created index for all the words (except those 'a', 'of' types) on all the fields? I ask this question because, I don't want to spend the memory on the indexes that I don't need.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You just need to add `"dynamic": "false"` to your mapping (same level as "_all").  This will do it at object level, but you can also set it at index level or in templates to set it for all indices. Information about this available [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic-mapping.html)

Comment: Thank you Olivier. I think I got it. See the example that I am putting in 'Answer your Question'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to exclude other fields from indexing you must specify them in mapping and set `index` property to `no` value. Here is an example

```
{
    "mappings": {
        "benefit": {
            "properties": {
                "subCategory": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "description": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "planName": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "no"
                },
                "bpi": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "no"
                },
                "category": {
                    "type": "string",
                    "index": "no"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I have a follow up question. I know I should post it a different question but I have already typed up the context for the question here, let me ask you this question. How do I put more weightage to the search results found in 'subCategory' over 'description'? any suggestions?

Comment: I figured this one by adding "boost" values to those two fields while creating the index. Thanks